# how to run native code in MAC OSX from Safari

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, safari, activex

I was wondering if it is possible to execute native code over MAC OS X but starting the execution from a Plug In or an Extension installed in SAFARI....

This is similar like Active x controls works in Windows OS. I would like to replicate the same behaviour for Mac osx lion and snow leopard. 
I dont know if it could be done using Java Applets or with adobe flash maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org). It's c++, not objective C, but you can use objective C++ in it to call your objective c functions.

A lot of people are using it to convert WebKit plugins to NPAPI now that Safari has dropped support for the former.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian for your answer, very useful, btw I found something related but I dont know wich one is better, I have to read more and compare the 2 approaches: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKit_PluginProgTopic.pdf

Comment: well, I'll give you a hint that will help with that decision: As of Safari 5.1, Webkit plugins are no longer supported, but NPAPI plugins are.